# Javascript does not work in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Inside `chrome-extension://<EXTENSION_ID>/hello.html`, the following code:

```
<script> alert("hi"); </script>
```

JS does not work?
How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use inline JavaScript in a Chrome extension as per enforced [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

You will need to get rid of it, by placing it in an external JS file.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: @ArtPip would you mind marking that as an answer, then?