# Chrome Extension: window.onload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This code works when I load the html file independent of the extension (in a different file... I've copied and pasted the portions that are relevant, but for some reason it doesn't work for this file).  Anyways, when I try to run this portion in my original extension, I get everything except the numerical values.  What's going on?

popup.html file:

```
<html>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Kill_Count.js"></script> 
</header>
<body>
<table>

  <td width="300">
  Stuff About Animals...
  </td>    
  <td>

      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">        

      <tr>
         <td>Pigs</td>
         <td align="right">
         <scpan id="Kill_Count"></span>
         <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = Kill_Count('Kill_Count');</script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>

  </td> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Kill_Count.js file:

```
function Kill_Count(id)
{
  var animal = "Pigs";
  var totalDeaths = 1375940758;
  var deathsPerSecond = totalDeaths/365/24/60/60/4;
  var deaths = 0;
  var timer = 1;
  setInterval(function() {    
     deaths = deathsPerSecond*timer;     
     result = deaths.toFixed();
     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
     timer++;
  }, 250);
}
```

Comment: Just today I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185406/javascript-does-not-work-in-chrome-extensions). Please research the topic.

Comment: This is not a webpage. In Chrome extensions you cannot put scripts in `<script>` tags, use any inline codes, or any form of `eval`.

Comment: I have researched this topic.

My Kill_Count.js file is already in an external file, how do I get it to function the same way within a extension popup?  I need to have something like window.onload, right?

Comment: The offending script here is the `<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = Kill_Count('Kill_Count');</script>`, which is an inline script.

Also, you probably want to write `window.onload = function() { Kill_Count('Kill_Count'); }` instead. This can be placed inside of the `Kill_Count.js` file.